# How to add a group id without looping?

Tags: r

I have dataframe such as:

```
   productid   ordernum   
   p1          10
   p2          20
   p3          30 
   p4          5
   p5          20
   p6          8
```

I would like to add another column, which called groupid,it groups the products together in sequence and once the sum(ordernum) reach 30 , assign a new group id,  e.g. the result should be

```
 productid   ordernum  groupid   
   p1          10        1
   p2          20        1 
   p3          30        2
   p4          5         3
   p5          20        3 
   p6          8         3
```

It is very easy to do by looping, by how can I achieve this without looping?

Comment: wouldn't you want the last one on its own?

Comment: no, 5+20=25 need add another 8 reach 33 >30, so last 3 will be assigned group 3

Comment: Then, I don't think you can... What is wrong with a `for` loop here? The obvious algorithm has `O(n)` complexity so it should still be very fast. Do you have gigantic data?

Comment: yes, the dataset is massive, I just think there must be some clever way to do it?

Comment: How many rows and what would be considered too slow? There are many ways you can write inefficient code, even after you settle on using `for`.

Comment: I think this is a job for Rcpp.

Comment: How massive is massive? A `for` loop should run fairly quickly for a simple cumulative sum task like this. But just in case it doesn't I wrote a `Rcpp` answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about a short `c++` written `for` loop using `Rcpp`. This little function takes a `numeric` vector, i.e. your `ordernum` column and a `threshold` argument (the cumulative sum you want to start a new ID from) and returns a vector of IDs of length equal to the input vector. Should run relatively quickly as it's a `for` loop in `c++`. The code snippet below will install `Rcpp` for you if you haven't already got it installed and will compile the function ready for use. Just copy and paste into R...

```
if( !require(Rcpp) ) install.packages("Rcpp"); require(Rcpp)
Rcpp::cppFunction( ' NumericVector grpid( NumericVector x , int threshold ){
  int n = x.size();
  NumericVector out(n);
  int tot = 0;
  int id = 1;
  for( int i = 0; i < n; ++i){
    tot += x[i];
    out[i] = id;
    if( tot >= threshold ){
      id += 1;
      tot = 0;
    }
  }
  return out;
}')
```

Then to use the function just use it like any other R function, supplying the relevant arguments:

```
df$groupid <- grpid( df$ordernum , 30 )
#  productid ordernum groupid
#1        p1       10       1
#2        p2       20       1
#3        p3       30       2
#4        p4        5       3
#5        p5       20       3
#6        p6        8       3
```

## BENCHMARKING COMPARISON

OP asked me to benchmark the Rcpp loop against a base R for loop. Here is the code and results. About a 400-fold increase in speed on a vector of 100,000 product ids:

```
set.seed(1)
x <- sample(30,1e5,repl=T)
for.loop <- quote({
    tot <- 0 
    id <- 1
    out <- numeric(length(x))
    for( i in 1:length(x) ){
        tot <- tot + x[i]
        out[i] <- id
        if( tot >= 30 ){
            tot <- 0
            id <- id + 1
        }
    }
})

rcpp.loop <- quote( out <- grpid(x,30))

require( microbenchmark )
print( bm , unit = "relative" , digits = 2 , "median" )
Unit: relative
            expr min  lq median  uq max neval
 eval(rcpp.loop)   1   1      1   1   1    50
  eval(for.loop) 533 462    442 428 325    50
```

Comment: speedwise, compare to loop direct in R , how faster this will be?

Comment: Why don't you try it and find out?! Use system.time () or try the package microbenchmark. I'll be able to do this tonight.