# cut with varied intervals?

Tags: r, filter, split, cut

I have a dataset with two variables, one is grouping variable, and the other is value. The data is sorted by value within each group. I want to cut the value variable into a factor within each group and less than the interval of diff(10). That is, if diff(val)>=10, than a new level is created. Below is a demo data, where `newgrp` is the new variable I want. Maybe `filter()` is desired here, but I have been in a daze with it for quite a while. Any thoughts?

```
  grp val  newgrp
    a 101   1   
    a 101   1
    a 102   1       
    a 110   1
    a 111   2 <-- a new level is created since 111 - 101 > 9
    a 112   2
    a 148   3 <-- a new level is created sine 152 - 148 > 9,
    a 157   3
    a 158   4 <-- a new level is created since 158 - 148>9
    b   8   1 <-- levels start over for group b
    b   9   1
    b  12   1
    b  17   1
    b  18   2
```

Comment: So what group would a person with a val of 142 have in grp=="a"? (I don't think you have unambiguously defined the splitting rule.)

Comment: OK, I edited the demo data, hope it now could be understood.

Comment: Isn't this very similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18530605/1412059), which got a nice Rcpp answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**

I don't think there's any way to avoid defining a function first that will loop through each vector, since two numbers (the "base" and "new group") need to be reset every time a large enough difference is encountered.

```
NewGroup = function(x)
{
    base = x[1]
    new = 1
    newgrp = c()
    for(i in seq_along(x))
    {
        if (x[i] - base > 9)
        {
            base = x[i]
            new = new + 1
        }
        newgrp[i] <- new
    }
    return(newgrp)
}

dt[,newgrp:=NewGroup(val),by=grp]

    grp val newgrp
 1:   a 101      1
 2:   a 101      1
 3:   a 102      1
 4:   a 110      1
 5:   a 111      2
 6:   a 112      2
 7:   a 148      3
 8:   a 157      3
 9:   a 158      4
10:   b   8      1
11:   b   9      1
12:   b  12      1
13:   b  17      1
14:   b  18      2
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, Señor. If there is a large leap in the value, then the division may not be corret to calculate levels. I edited the demo data, hope that is more clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
do.call(rbind, by(yourdf, yourdf$grp, function(df) within(df, newgrp <- cumsum(c(1,diff(val))>9))))
```

Replace `yourdf` with your dataframe.